# Program Can't sort Employee List

Tags: java, java-stream

I'am making a java program using streams which sort employee based on their salary.
Program is given below :-

```
public class EmployeeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Employee e1 = new Employee(10000, "Adam");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(5000, "Peter");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(14000, "Robin");

        List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(e1, e2, e3);

        Collections.sort(list,
                (emp1, emp2) -> e1.getSalary() > e2.getSalary() ? 1 : e2.getSalary() > e1.getSalary() ? -1 : 0);

        list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
    }

}
```

The output for this code is :-

```
Employee [salary=10000, name=Adam]
Employee [salary=5000, name=Peter]
Employee [salary=14000, name=Robin]
```

What's the issue with this code?

Comment: Maybe just use `Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary)` rather than nesting ternary operators.

Comment: You've made a typo. Use `emp1.getSalary()` and `emp2.getSalary()` instead of `e1.getSalary()` and `e2.getSalary()`

Comment: @cheseaux That is an amazing eagle-eyed catch. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a typo in the body of the sort method.
Instead of using `emp1` and `emp2` you used `e1` and `e2` which are the instances of the employees you instantiated above.

So basically what you wrote gets evaluated to :

```
Collections.sort(list, (emp1, emp2) -> 10000 > 5000 ? 1 : 5000 > 10000 ? -1 : 0)
```

Which is

```
Collections.sort(list, (emp1, emp2) -> 1)
```

What you want to write is

```
Collections.sort(list, (emp1, emp2) -> emp1.getSalary() > emp2.getSalary() ? 1 : emp2.getSalary() > emp1.getSalary() ? -1 : 0);
```

or shorter/better, as stated in the comments

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getSalary));
```